# Android Unexpected Behaviour on first run

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

When I install an development App from an apk (sideloaded) and press "Open" in the install dialogue, the user is first asked by the App to register with our server.

The first two steps of this are to get the user to enter an email address and then to get them to enter the PIN (which was sent to the email address they just entered).

What I am seeing from the run from installation, is then when the user sends the App to background to go and read their email, bringing the App back forces the user to enter their email address again.

Likewise if they do get through registration (say by reading their email elsewhere), if they then send the App to the background and then bring it back to the foreground, they are asked to login (even though they are logged in).

The important thing to say is that this does not happen on any subsequent run, only the one following installation.  Neither have I seen it happen before when running in debug mode at any time, when uploaded to a device from the debugger.

The Activity which gets the email address is the same one which gets the PIN
The Activity which runs after registration is complete, is a different activity from the login Activity which is invoked when it comes back from background on the first run.

Can anyone explain what is happening here, why it only happens on the first run, and how I can rectify it.

Thanks.